# Custom shortcode being shown in WPBakery backend rather than the block

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a nested element called `Hero Slider`. `Hero slider` is the container and it can only contain a `Slider item`.

However, my shortcode is being shown in the WPBakery backend maybe suggesting a syntax error, but I cannot see anything that is causing it to appear this way:

[image]

The block doesn't even appear when adding a new element.

**Here's my custom element: (init.php)**

```
<?php

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) die('-1');

class vcHeroSlider extends WPBakeryShortCode {

    // 1. Define constants at compile time (used in mapping)
    const slug = 'tp_hero_slider';
    const base = 'tp_hero_slider';

    // 2. Integrate with hooks
    function __construct() {
        // For the parent wrapper
        add_action( 'vc_before_init', array( $this, 'tp_heroSlider_mapping' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'tp_hero_slider', array( $this, 'tp_heroSlider_html' ));
        // For child / nested
        add_action( 'vc_before_init', array( $this, 'tp_heroSlider_content_mapping' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'tp_hero_slider_content', array( $this, 'tp_heroSlider_content_html' ));
    }

    // 3. Map for parent element
    public function tp_heroSlider_mapping() {
        vc_map(
            array(
                'icon'                    => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/src/images/html.svg',
                'name'                    => __( 'Hero Slider' , "text-domain" ),
                'base'                    => 'tp_hero_slider',
                'description'             => __( 'Add slick slider to your page.', "text-domain" ),
                'as_parent'               => array('only' => 'tp_hero_slider_content'), // set as parent of the content map/html
                'content_element'         => true,
                'show_settings_on_create' => false,
                "js_view"                 => 'VcColumnView',
                "category"                => __('Hero', "text-domain" ),
                'params'                  => array(
                    array(
                        "type" => "textfield",
                        "heading" => __( "Extra Class Name", "text-domain" ),
                        "param_name" => "el_class",
                        "description" => __( "Extra class to be customized via CSS", "text-domain" )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'css_editor',
                        'heading' => __( 'Custom Design Options', "text-domain" ),
                        'param_name' => 'css',
                        'group' => __( 'Design options', "text-domain" ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
    }

    // 4. Map for child element
    public function tp_heroSlider_content_mapping() {
        vc_map(
            array(
                'icon'                      => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/src/images/html.svg',
                'name'                      => __('Slider Item', "text-domain" ),
                'base'                      => 'tp_hero_slider_content',
                'description'               => __( 'Add slide to hero.', "text-domain" ),
                "category"                  => __('Content', 'text-domain'),
                'content_element'           => true,
                'as_child'                  => array('only' => 'tp_hero_slider'),
                'params'                    => array(

                    array(
                        'type' => 'textfield',
                        'heading' => __( 'Title', 'text-domain'),
                        'param_name' => 'title',
                        'value' => esc_html__( '', 'text-domain'),
                        'admin_label' => true,
                        'weight' => 0,
                        'group' => __( 'Content', 'my-text-domain' ),
                    ),

                    array(
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'class' => '',
                        'heading' => __( 'Standfirst', 'text-domain'),
                        'param_name' => 'standfirst',
                        'value' => esc_html__( '', 'text-domain'),
                        'admin_label' => false,
                        'weight' => 0,
                        'group' => __( 'Content', 'my-text-domain' ),
                    )

                ),
            )
        );
    }

    // 5. Mapping markup of parent
    public function tp_heroSlider_html( $atts, $content = null) {
        $output = '';
        $el_class = '';

        extract(
            shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'el_class'  => '',
                ), $atts
            )
        );

        static $i = 0;

        $output = '<div id="slickslider-'.$i++.'" class="Slick-Slider heroSlider">'. do_shortcode($content) .'</div>';

        return $output;

    }

    // 6. Mapping markup of child
    public function tp_heroSlider_content_html( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $output = '';

        extract(
            shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'title'                 => '',
                    'standfirst'            => '',
                ), $atts
            )
        );

        $background_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(intval($background_img), 'full');
        $background_img = $background_img[0];

        $output .= '
                    <!-- Slide -->
                    <div class="heroSlider__slide">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    ';

        $output .= '
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                                <div class="col-10 col-md-6 d-flex flex-column text-center text-lg-left content">';

                                    if (!empty($title)) { 
                                        $output .= '<h1>' . $title . '</h1>'; 
                                    }

                                    if (!empty($standfirst)) {  
                                        $output .= '<p class="standfist">' . $standfirst . '</p>'; 
                                    }

        $output .= '
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Slide -->
                ';

        return $output;

    }

}

// 7. Add the container functionality (so you can choose a slider element within the hero_slider element
if(class_exists('WPBakeryShortCodesContainer')){
    class WPBakeryShortCode_tp_hero_slider extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {}
}

if(class_exists('WPBakeryShortCode')){
    class WPBakeryShortCode_tp_hero_slider_content extends WPBakeryShortCode {}
}

new vcHeroSlider(); ?>
```

How I've added new element:

```
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_before_init_actions' );

function vc_before_init_actions() {
    $theme = get_template_directory();
    require_once( $theme.'/vc_elements/hero-slider/init.php');]
}
```

Although I don't believe the above is the issue, because I have several other elements defined like that and they all work.

Comment: Why Syntax error? there is no any syntax error.  In your may be got PHP notice error for undefined background_img variable. Your code is works fine on my end. Please check error log. May be cause broken in editor, delete this in editor and create new one

Comment: @NandLal - $background_img doesn't seem to be the issue, I'm not seeing any errors related to it and a `var_dump($background-img)` returns the URL of the image (which is fine). Also, I can't re-add the element within the editor because it doesn't even appear as an option when I click "Add Element"

Comment: I know $background_img is not issue. Your code is working fine on my. Did you check error in console? also try to add element on front side. disable other WPbakery addons

Comment: @NandLal - In your test, does the element 'Hero slider' appear in a tab called `Hero`? I do have slick errors in console, but the element should still load in the WP backend? And yes I have required it before init (question has been updated to show how).

Comment: I believe you are missing the `holder` param